# The minimizing problem over a sequence of shrinking balls

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces, calculus-of-variations

Let $B(0,r)\subset \mathbb R^3$ be a ball centered at $0$ with radius $r$. Define 
$$  \mathcal A_r:=\{u\in H_0^1(B(0,r)),\,\,\|u\|_{L^{q+1}}=1\}$$
where $1<q<5$. Hence we know that each $\mathcal A_r$ is weakly closed with respect to $H_0^1$ norm.

Now I am interesting in to see whether I can find a constant $C>0$ such that 
$$ \max_{r>0}\min_{u\in\mathcal A_r}\int_{B(0,r)}|\nabla u|^2\leq C $$

Could this be possible? If not, please provided me a counterexample as well. Thank you!

---

Update:

It looks to me that if $1+\epsilon<q<5$ will work, but not just $1<q<5$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested on overflow by Pietro Majer (if I did not make a computational mistake): writing $u=v(x/r)$, $u\in A_r\Leftrightarrow v\in B_r$,  with
$$
B_r=\{u\in H^1_0(B(0,1)) : \|u\|_{L^{q+1}} = r^{\frac{-d}{q+1}}\},
$$ 
and you want 
$$
\max_{r>0} \min_{w\in B_r} r^{d}\int_{B(0,1)}|\nabla u|^{2}\leq C.
$$
Now, $B_r = r^{\frac{-d}{q+1}}B_1$, therefore you want
$$
\max_{r>0} \inf_{w\in B_1} r^{d\frac{q-1}{q+1}} \int_{B(0,1)}|\nabla u|^{2}\leq C.
$$
The two problems are now decoupled, so either 
$$
\inf_{w\in B_1}  \int_{B(0,1)}|\nabla u|^{2}=0,
$$
in which case the constant $C$ is zero, or not and the upper bound is infinite if $q>1$, or $q=1$, and the bound is just the first eigenvalue of the Laplacian. Now, for $1<q<5$ thanks to Sobolev's embeddings, the inf is a min and is not zero, therefore there is no such $C$.

So for $q>1$ no, and for $q=1$, yes.

Comment: Yes, I use similar argument proves that as long as $q>5$ it is good. Hence, my statement does not work if $1<q<5$